# My GLM runs with no warnings but when a GLMM with random effect, 3 warnings

Tags: r, glmm, glmmtmb

I have a dataset with 4 columns of interest:
Event (1 or 0, binary)
Nymph (Y or N, categorical)
Date (Dates from 2023-04-03 to 2023-05-02)
Tag (categorical, individual IDs (77 distinct Tags)

I have fitted a GLM with no issues:

```r
glm.wake <- glm(Event.binary ~ Nymph + Date, data = wake_df_overlap, family = binomial)
```

I want to include Tag as a random effect so modified the model:

```r
glmm.wake <- glmer(Event.binary ~ Nymph + Date + (1|Tag), data = wake_df_overlap, family = binomial)
```

However, now I get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling 
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

I don't really understand what's happening. I also tried the glmmTMB package

```
glmm_wake <- glmmTMB(Event.binary ~ Nymph + Date + (1 | Tag), data = wake_df_overlap, family = binomial)
```

and got the following warnings

```
Warning messages:
1: In .checkRankX(TMBStruc, control$rank_check) :
  fixed effects in conditional model are rank deficient
2: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

Edit: here is how data is coded

```
class(wake_df_overlap$Date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" as.Date('2023-05-02'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I suspect that this might have to do with the way that the `Date` variable was coded in the data. Please edit the question to provide details of how numerical values were assigned to `Date`. I could see this type of thing happening, for example, if you used a format that assigned seconds since the beginning of 1970 to each observation.

Comment: Hi @EdM, code edited to show what I did to date. Any ideas?

Comment: Under the hood, `POSIXct` objects are indeed in seconds.  That's guaranteed to lose about ten significant decimal digits of precision right off the bat.  A good choice for your data would be to represent dates as (decimal) days elapsed since a convenient start date like 2023-04-01.  See the help for `difftime` for computing date/time differences.

Comment: solved, thank you @EdM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the fixed-effects model, which is fit by a solution to a simple matrix equation, the solution to the mixed model depends on more complicated numerical optimization to estimate random intercepts. Random intercepts are the estimated values when all predictors are at values of 0. If some types of predictor values are much farther away from 0 than the others, that can lead to problems.

Your binary predictor is coded as 0/1, while your `Date` values are on the order of `1.7e+9`:

```
unclass(as.POSIXct(as.Date("2023-05-02")))
# [1] 1682985600
# attr(,"tzone")
```

I think you can see why the software complained that "Some predictor variables are on very different scales," which leads to the numerical problem that you found. Follow the suggestion from @whuber in a comment, and transform your `Date` values to a scale that better represents the time differences of interest.

After that, also consider whether you should model the `Date` values as you are, linearly related to the log-odds of `Event.binary`. Such models typically require some more flexible modeling of a continuous predictor like `Date`, for example with a regression spline.